# Where can I find gpt-35-turbo in the Microsoft Pricing calculator?

Tags: gpt, azure-ml

Where can I find gpt-35-turbo in the [Microsoft Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)? I don't see gpt-35-turbo in the model list:

[image]

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/openai-service/ says "NA".

However, I do see gpt-35-turbo on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/concepts/models. So I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gpt-35-turbo now shows up in the [Microsoft Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/):

[image]